# A software for setting a different quote each day as a desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows, wallpaper

I am looking for a software to show customizable text every day on my pc desktop. Could anyone recommend me such an application?

It is important that the software lets me customize the quotes.

I have 365 quotes in an Excel speadsheet, and I want to set one of these quotes each day as wallpaper.

Comment: Would you like the text as a wallpaper, as a widget, or a pop-out window? Please add some more detail to the question. Take a look at [this post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/6834) on how to improve it

Comment: If you want to customize the quotes: Do you want to add 365 per year manually? Then you could use any calendar :) Asked differently: What should the source(s) be? How do you want to customize?

Comment: @Timmy ->I have 365 qoutes in excel file,and i want to set qoute of day as wallpaper.

Comment: What format is the Excel file in? That might affect what software you can use.

Comment: it is one column with 365 row(unicode text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have a quoteless image to start from, you could use a [python](http://python.org) script to extract the line for the current day, (you need 366 in leap years), either from a plain text file or by using the [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.3) library.  Once you have the line you can use [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to apply the text onto the image to use as wallpaper and either overwrite the default file used by windows or trigger a "set as wallpaper" something like:

```
import ctypes

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 # According to http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=97142

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "myimage.jpg" , 0)
```